# Finding first word after regex match

Tags: java, regex

How do I grab the first word after my match?

For example, once I find `Car`, how do I grab `Chevy`?

```
public class NewExtractDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "I have the following Car: Chevy, Truck: Ford, Van: Honda";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Car|Truck|Van)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

        List<String> Search = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found a " + m.group() + ".");
            Search.add(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [capturing groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html):

```
(Car|Truck|Van):\s*(\w+)
```

Now `.group(1)` will return `Car` and `.group(2)` will return `Chevy`.

---

```
String input = "I have the following Car: Chevy, Truck: Ford, Van: Honda";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Car|Truck|Van):\\s*(\\w+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + "\t" + m.group(2));
}
```

```
Car     Chevy
Truck   Ford
Van     Honda
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a constant to avoid recompiling the regular expression each time.

```
/* The regex pattern that you need: (?<=(Car|Truck|Van): )(\w+) */
private static final REGEX_PATTERN = 
                                 Pattern.compile("(?<=(Car|Truck|Van): )(\\w+)");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "I have the following Car: Chevy, Truck: Ford, Van: Honda";
    Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Chevy
Ford
Honda
```